Confusion on Shankar's Motivation for the Dirac delta Function
I was reading Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics and got confused on page 60, where he motivates the delta function from the normalization problem of the inner product for function spaces. We start with the completeness relation
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^b |x^\prime\rangle\langle x^\prime| \ dx^\prime= I.
\end{equation}
Then, we get
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^b \langle x|x^\prime\rangle\langle x^\prime| f \rangle \ dx^\prime = \langle x | f \rangle = f(x).
\end{equation}
Shanker defines the delta function $\delta(x,x^\prime)$ to be $\delta(x, x^\prime) := \langle x|x^\prime \rangle$.
We assume that $|x\rangle$ and $|x^\prime \rangle$ are basis vectors in this space. Therefore, $\delta(x, x^\prime)$ vanishes if $x \not= x^\prime$.
Thus, we may rewrite the integral as
\begin{equation}
\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} \delta(x, x^\prime) f(x^\prime) \ dx^\prime = f(x),
\end{equation} for any $\epsilon > 0$.
For small enough $\epsilon$, we can also claim that $\forall x^\prime \in (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon), \ f(x) \approx f(x^\prime)$. (If we assume that all elements in the space are continuous functions)
Therefore, we get the relation
\begin{equation}
\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} \delta(x, x^\prime) \ dx^\prime = 1,
\end{equation} for small enough $\epsilon$.
I am ok with Shankar's chain of reasoning so far, but I have trouble justifying what he does next.
1. He claims that $\delta(x, x^\prime)$ depends only on the difference $x -  x^\prime$.
2. He defines the Dirac delta function $\delta(x - x^\prime)$ as the function with the property that $\delta(x - x^\prime) = 0$ if $x \not= x^\prime$ and \begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} \delta(x, x^\prime) \ dx^\prime = 1,
\end{equation} $ a < x < b$.
I understand why the delta function only has a dependence on the difference from later derivations of the delta function with the Fourier transform, but is there another reason why Shankar can claim that the function only has a difference dependence here? Also, what allows Shankar to jump from the bound $(x - \epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ to $(a,b)$ for the relation \begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} \delta(x, x^\prime) \ dx^\prime = 1,
\end{equation} $ a < x < b$?
Here is the page in Shankar that I am referring to:


Looks to me that (1.10.16) in the image is the definition of Dirac delta function and hasn't yet been used to change $x\pm\epsilon$ to $a,b$.

Is the $x \pm \epsilon$ equation then simply to give some intuition for the definition of the Dirac delta function? I guess $a,b$ bound requirement for the integral places a stronger condition onto the delta function.

Let $a<x-\epsilon$ and $b>x+\epsilon$, then $\int_a^b\delta(x-x'),\mathrm{d}x'=1$ holds also since the limits still contain the point $x$.

If you're willing to accept that the integral definition implies that $\delta(x,x')$ has to be zero unless $x=x'$, then it trivially follows that $\delta(x,x')=\delta(x-x')$ (since $\delta$ is zero unless $x-x'=0$).

But this relation can only hold because we argued that $f(x^\prime) = f(x)$ for $x^\prime$ really close to $x$, hence the restricted bound that we set using $\delta$. I was reading the answer link. There Feyman seems to argue that the relation using $(-\infty, \infty)$ holds if $f(x) = 1$. *Edit: I understand now. It helped with my intuition to think about the Delta function as strictly being zero outside of a very small area around $x$.

Nascent δ is even.

For the first question, regarding the dependence of the delta function on the difference $x-x'$, that is just how the delta function is defined. It is important to note that, rigorously, the delta function is in fact a distribution.
For your second question, any interval $(a,b)$, with $a<x$ and $b>x$ contains the infinitesimal interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, and since the delta function is zero everywhere except at $x'=x$, or, equivalently, at $x-x'=0$, you can extend this infinitesimal interval to a finite one when taking the integral.

@Andrew's comment above helped me better understand my first question.
